# Where is Pride's Homunculus tattoo?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series

My brother and I were talking about the symbolism behind the location of the Homunculi's tattoo's location (i.e. Greed's is on his hand because he wants to get a hold of everything, Gluttony's is on his tongue because he wants to eat everything, etc.) and after reading all of the Fullmetal Alchemist manga three times over, neither of us could remember the location of Pride's Homunculus tattoo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the manga and *Brotherhood*, Pride does not have an Ouroboros tattoo. He instead has only a small circular mark on his true form's body.

Below is an image of said mark, but definitely contains spoilers for anyone not finished episode 37 of *Brotherhood* (and perhaps could be considered spoiler material for anyone who has finished episode 64).

> [image: Pride in his "true form"]

Comment: This mark is present only after the defeat to Elric, What about before that?

Comment: @Bej: the mark probably wasn't there. Note that post-Promised Day, the mark on Selim's forehead is rather low, so it doesn't seem like it'd be hidden pre-Promised Day under Selim's hair. (Some references in my answer [here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/38276/2604).) It also doesn't make sense for Pride's _shell_ (which is only _holding_ his true form and isn't his actual body) to have the mark when it would probably only arouse suspicion.

Answer (score 1):

On the FMA Wikia it states and from general knowledge on my part in the 2009 & Manga...

> Pride is the only Homunculus without an Ouroboros, instead having a circular mark on his true form's forehead.

Oroborus meaning...

> "He Who eats his tail"

But in the 2003 Anime from my memory, is that...

> Prides Ouroborus is located on his left eye and in the 2009 Manga share a similarity to another Homunculus, Wrath (Also his Father)

[image: In the Anime] [image: In the Manga]

Just pictures of what the Ouroborus looks like. On the left is in the Anime and on the right the Manga.

More information can be obtained [here](http://fma.wikia.com/wiki/Pride) and [here](http://fma.wikia.com/wiki/Ouroboros).